# React-Router: Link updates URL but view does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I've tried multiple solutions but none seem to work so here's the code:

**Expected Behavior:**

- Click on new Deck button
- Enter new Deck name and press enter, new deck is added
- Click on new Deck,get redirected to /deck/:deckId in the url, Where deckId is the id of the deck
- VisibleCards component fires and returns a div containing current deckId

**Actual Behavior:**

- Click on new Deck button
- Enter new Deck name and press enter, new deck is added
- Click on new Deck,get redirected to /deck/:deckId  in the url, Where
  deckId is the id of the deck
- VisibleCards does not fire, it fires if i refresh the page manually

*Also please note that if i enter the url manually, the VisibleCards component fires *

app.js:

```
//STORE
const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers));
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);

function run(){
    let state = store.getState();
    console.log(state);
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="holder">


                    <div className="sidebar">
                        <Route path='/' component={App}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="VisibleCards">
                        <Route path='/deck/:deckId' component={VisibleCards}/>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </Router>       
        </Provider>,document.getElementById('root'));
}
run();
store.subscribe(run)

window.show = ()=>{store.dispatch(showAddDeck())};
window.hide = ()=>{store.dispatch(hideAddDeck())};
window.add = ()=>{store.dispatch(addDeck(new Date().toString()))};
```

VisibleCards.js:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  //console.log(ownProps.location.pathname);
  console.log(`currently is visible cards.js , ownprops is: `);
  console.log(ownProps)
  return {state};
}

class Cards extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        //console.log("Currently in VisibleCards, props are:")
        //console.log(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>{this.props.match.params.deckId}</div>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Cards));
```

App.js

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  //console.log(ownProps.location.pathname);
  console.log(`currently is App.js , state is: `);
  console.log(state);
  console.log(`currently is App.js , ownProps is: `)

  //var deckId = (ownProps.location.pathname).substring(6);
  console.log(ownProps)
  //console.log(state);
  return {state};
}

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
        // navigated!
        console.log("here");
      }
      else{
        console.log("In app.js else statment,this.props are:")
        console.log(this.props);
        //console.log("nextprops are:")
        //console.log(nextprops);
      }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <h1>{this.props.deckId}</h1>
                <Sidebar/>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Sidebar.js

```
class Sidebar extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.createDeck = this.createDeck.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.add)
        if(el){el.focus();}
    }
    createDeck(e){
        if(e.which!==13)return
        //console.log("here");
        console.log(this);
        var name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.add).value;
        //console.log("here");
        this.props.addDeck(name);
        this.props.hideAddDeck();
    }


    render(){
        let props = this.props
        //console.log(props)
        return (
            <div className="sidebar">
                <h2>All decks</h2>
                <button onClick = {e=>this.props.showAddDeck()  }>
                    New Deck
                </button>
                <ul>
                    {props.decks.map((deck,i)=>
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link  to={`/deck/${deck.id}`} >{deck.name}</Link>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>

                {props.addingDeck && <input ref='add' onKeyPress = {this.createDeck}></input>}
            </div>)
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({decks,addingDeck})=>({
    decks,
    addingDeck
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>({
    addDeck : name => dispatch(addDeck(name)),
    showAddDeck : () => dispatch(showAddDeck()),
    hideAddDeck : () => dispatch(hideAddDeck())
})



export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar));
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess the component is triggering componentWillUpdate() probably the component is receiving the new props if you are performing the action from the same route

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Read the id in the new props on Update and setState with the new values to re-render the component. First validate that the new props hold the new Id

Comment: Do you get the new id in the props? is the componentWillUpdate called?

Comment: componentWillUpdate is called in VisibleCards only when refreshing , it does not get called as expected when i click on one of my decks

Comment: Does it happen from the same route or a different (/deck/:deckId_1 -> /deck/:deckId_2) or (/some_route -> /deck/:deckId)?

Comment: Both, if the url is as expected and i click on the same deck again it still does not get called

Comment: A hack would be 2 consecutive redirects .. just for testing redirect to root then to the deck after each other and see if it works or if any redirect works at all. (couldn't find it in the code above - the redirect part)